# Is there a way to create custom properties in Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, events, kivy, subclassing

Sometimes `ObjectProperty` isn't suitable. This is because it only raises an event when the value of the object changes.

But what about when an attribute of the object changes? An event isn't raised.

Consider a class:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

And a Kivy widget:

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    point = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, point):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.point = point

    def on_point(self, obj, value):
        # do something
```

What happens when I change something about `point`?

```
w = MyWidget(Point(0, 0))
w.point.x = 10
# callback not called!
```

The callback wasn't called because as far as `ObjectProperty` is concerned, `point` hasn't changed. But I want changes to `x` and `y` to be counted as changes and raise an event.

Similar to the way `ListProperty` knows to raise an event when the length of the list changes.

For this, I think I need to create a `Property` subclass `PointProperty`.

But I haven't found documentation regarding how to do that. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new property type for this; build big things out of small things. Make those `x` and `y` numeric properties.

```
class Point(EventDispatcher):

    x = NumericProperty(0)
    y = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def on_x(self, obj, value):
        print 'x changed:', value

    def on_y(self, obj, value):
        print 'y changed:', value
```

Then

```
w = MyWidget(Point(0, 0))
w.point.x = 10
# 'x changed: 10'
```

Comment: Nice idea, but that's still not perfect. What if I'm using third party classes which aren't related to Kivy? Also, I'm using Kivy's `Vector` class, which isn't built this way (this is what led me to this question).

Comment: @AvivCohn It's pointless to track changes of the *entire* object, because it would add a lot of needless computation, slowing down your application. I don't know what exactly are you trying to do by attempting to track all fields on an external class object; but anyway, you could just wrap it.